# How works Stack and Bias and how avoid error "Segmentation Fault" GNU Assembler?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, att, stack-memory

In-first I wanna Apoligize about Non-English comments in code-examples
I do not quite understand how the stack works and how the stack alignment limit is calculated and HOW to align it.
For example, try reverse x86(-m32) code on x86_x64:

```
.data
printf_format:
        .string "%d\n"
 
.text
.global main
main:
        movl  $0, %eax          /* в %eax будет результат, поэтому в 
                                   начале его нужно обнулить         */
        movl  $10, %ecx         /* 10 шагов цикла                    */
 
sum:
        addl  %ecx, %eax        /* %eax = %eax + %ecx                */
        loop  sum
 
        /* %eax = 55, %ecx = 0 */
 
/*
 * следующий код выводит число в %eax на экран и завершает программу
 */
        pushl %eax
        pushl $printf_format
        call  printf
        addl  $8, %esp
 
        movl  $0, %eax
        ret
```

I try to reverse on:

```
.data
print_format:
        .string "%d\n"
.text
.global main
main:
        push %rbp
        mov %rsp, %rbp /*значение стека переносим в rbp(то есть указатель стека на rbp в rbp)*/
        sub  $0x10,%rsp /*вычитаем десять из регистра стека*/
        movl $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)/*заносим ноль в значение -1 в стек*/
        movl $0xa,-0x8(%rbp)/*заносим 10 в значение -2 в стеке*/
        mov -0x8(%rbp),%eax/*заносим значение стека -2 в регистр счётчика*/
sum:
        add %eax,-0x4(%rbp)/*добавляем в значение стека -1(окончательная сумма всех чисел) значение из счётчика*/
        subl $0x1,-0x8(%rbp)/*вычитаем единицу из значения стека -2(которое будет в счётчике, т.е уменьшаем значенние счётчика)*/
        cmpl $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)/*сравниваем равно ли значение стека -2 нулю*/
        jne  sum/*переходим на sum, если нет*/
        /*Дальше вывод*/
        mov -0x4(%rbp), %eax/*кидаем в счётчик окончательный ответ*/
        mov %eax, %esi
        lea 0xe99(%rip), %rax
        mov %rax,%rdi
        mov $0x0, %eax
        call printf
        mov $0x0,%eax
        pop %rbp
        leave
        ret
```

I Know about new registers for syscalls in Linux, BUT ALWAYS on My tryes works with Stack I had error "Segmentation fault". Also if I don't use linux syscalls And just push the values ​​on the stack. I try to just copy code from Youtube guides and had the same error, but in the same time on video all works right(And I...Do all what was in the video. How that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpIkRtI3pOQ(Again sorry for Non-English sources))
Also I get examples from that [https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2_Linux_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_C#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
Sources and more books, how NASM UNIX SYSTEM GUIDE and other books about that.

So...If say about fact, that I have that Error on GNU assembler, Nasm and MASM assembler, I think that's problem in stack only and align that.Can anybody explain what I don't do right, that NOT ANY code(also in copy-paste) don't work?

Comment: The `lea 0xe99` should of course be `print_format` and the `leave` already includes `pop rbp` so remove that.

Comment: Try also asking on https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Oh...Yeah, about ru.stackoverflow, Something I earned xD
But in Series, I don't understand why always i have segmentation fault. Also, remove pop rbp and lea 0xe99 I have, expected, the same error.

Comment: What command did you use to create the binary? Works fine here with those fixes.